# Show results which belong to 2 cateogires

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

I have the latest version of SuperSearch installed on EE 2.7.3.

I am trying to perform a search which fetches entries that belonged to 2 categories.
I need the output to be like this `category="Teeth&&Gums"`, at the moment the auto generated search URL is `category="Teeth+Gums"`

Do i need to put a certain parameter in?
Functionally the search is working fine.

Here is the code I have

```
{exp:super_search:search}
    <ul>
        {exp:channel:categories
            category_group="1"
            channel="resources"
            disable="category_fields"
            show_empty="no"
            style="linear"
        }
        <li>
            {exp:super_search:variables}
                <label for="category_{category_url_title}">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="category_{category_url_title}" name="category[]" value="{category_url_title}"  {if super_search_category_{category_url_title}} checked="checked" {/if} >
                    {category_name}
                </label>
            {/exp:super_search:variables}
         </li>
         {/exp:channel:categories}
    </ul>

    <ul>
        {exp:channel:categories
            category_group="2"
            channel="resources"
            disable="category_fields"
            show_empty="no"
            style="linear"
        }
        <li>
            {exp:super_search:variables}
                <label for="category_{category_url_title}">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="category_{category_url_title}" name="category[]" value="{category_url_title}"  {if super_search_category_{category_url_title}} checked="checked" {/if} >
                    {category_name}
                </label>
            {/exp:super_search:variables}
         </li>
         {/exp:channel:categories}
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter!">
{/exp:super_search:search}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want your url segment to display url.com/category1&&category2 not url.com/category1+category2 ?

Comment: @mattsidjohn Correct, for when I submit the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your category list do:
value="{category_name}&&"
SuperSearch will recognize this and strip the "&&" off the last category chosen